# Running loop on Java method

Tags: java, loops, numbers, boolean, calculator

So I have this assignment for class about doing something that implemented methods. I made this really simple program to give you a lucky number of the day. But for some reason, I couldn't get it to run properly more than twice.

The version I'm posting doesn't contain the loop, but I tried about 10 different ways and it just wouldn't work. Either it would keep spitting out numbers endlessly, or it would print out the welcome lines again instead of just the "would you like another number y/n" line. If someone could just help me figured out how I should have organized it so that the loop only displays this line:

```
Would you like to receive another number? y/n
```

and then if the user decides yes, the intro method runs again and that line displays again until uses presses "n"

here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger; 
import java.util.Random; 

public class MinOppgave2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    menu();
}

    public static void menu(){
    //intro text
    System.out.println("Welcome to lucky number of the day!");
    System.out.println("What kind of number would you like today?");
    intro();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Would you like to receive another number? y/n");
    String txtinput = input.nextLine();
                if (txtinput.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
            intro();
                }
            else if (txtinput.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
                System.out.println("That's all for now, have a nice day!");
            }
    System.out.println("That's all for now, have a nice day!");
    }

    public static void intro(){
    // user choice
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please choose between: even odd or prime");
    String text1 = input.nextLine();
    //if/else user choice arguments
    if (text1.equalsIgnoreCase("even"))
        Evennum();  
        else if (text1.equalsIgnoreCase("odd"))
            Oddnum();
        else if (text1.equalsIgnoreCase("prime"))
            Prime();
        else
            menu();
    }

    public static void Evennum(){
        // random number generator
        int num = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        num = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
        while (!isEven(num)) {          
            num = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(num);
    }

    public static void Oddnum(){
        // random number generator
        int num = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        num = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;

        while (!isOdd(num)) {          
            num = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(num);
    }

    public static void Prime(){
        // random number generator
        int num = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        num = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
        while (!isPrime(num)) {          
            num = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(num); 
    }


    // prime checker
    private static boolean isPrime(int numin){
        if (numin <= 3 || numin % 2 == 0) 
            return numin == 2 || numin == 3;
        int divisor = 3;
        while ((divisor <= Math.sqrt(numin)) && (numin % divisor != 0)) 
            divisor += 2;
        //true/false prime answer
        return numin % divisor != 0;
    }

    private static boolean isEven(int numin){
        //math argument for even number
        return (numin % 2) == 0;
    }

    private static boolean isOdd(int numin){
        //math argument for even number
        return (numin % 2) == 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong recursion on the wrong place...

Try this:

```
public static void intro() {
  System.out.println("Welcome to lucky number of the day!");
  System.out.println("What kind of number would you like today?");
}

public static String takeInput() {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  return input.nextLine();
}

public static boolean pickNumber() {
  System.out.println("Would you like to receive another number? y/n");
  if (!takeInput().equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    System.out.println("That's all for now, have a nice day!");
    return false;
  }

  System.out.println("Please choose between: even odd or prime");
  String chosen = takeInput();
  //if/else user choice arguments
  if (chosen.equalsIgnoreCase("even"))
    Evennum();
  else
    if (chosen.equalsIgnoreCase("odd"))
      Oddnum();
    else
      if (chosen.equalsIgnoreCase("prime"))
        Prime();

  return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  intro();
  while (pickNumber())
    ;
}
```